# Mostrar fecha y hora actual en C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2015 y quiero hacer que se me muestre por pantalla la "fecha" y la "hora actual" en C++, para ello estoy llamando a las funciones: getLocalTime y getTimeFormat.

Tengo este código dentro del main:

```
printf(GetLocalTime);
printf(GetTimeFormat);
```

Y al ejecutarlo me muestra lo siguiente por pantalla:

```
ÿ00B3104BlötÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ<ÿU<ìQ¡¼Pöt3Å%EüV<5üWöt.ö._U
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para poder mostrarlo por pantalla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como lo haces, no estás llamado a la función `GetLocalTime` (o `GetTimeFormat`), estás enviando a `printf` la dirección de memoria de la función (le pasas el nombre de la función directamente), cuando `printf` espera que su primer parámetro sea una cadena de carácteres. Por tanto, en tu código, `printf` está tratando la dirección de memoria de la función, como si fuera una cadena de carácteres, de ahí que te imprima cosas raras. Tendrías que hacer algo como (de acuerdo a lo poco que he ojeado la documentación de Windows; date cuenta que esas funciones no son estándar `C`, y tampoco entiendo porqué te exigen hacerlo de esa manera):

```
// lo suficientemente grande para obtener el formato. La doc de 
// windows, como no, no especifica como de grande debe ser.
char formato[30]; 
int status = getTimeFormat(LOCALE_CUSTOM_DEFAULT,
      TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT, NULL, NULL, formato, 30);

if (status == 0)
   printf("Error. Aun estoy aprendiendo.");
else
   printf("%s", formato);

printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

En C++11 puedes utilizar [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) de la cabecera [`iomanip`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S") << std::endl;
}
```

[`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) es un *stream manipulator*, así que también puede utilizarse junto a  [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) para convertir una fecha en una cadena de caracteres:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S");
    auto str = oss.str();

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Tomada de [Current date and time as string answer en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358111/255257)

Comment: Buenas, tiene que ser con la función: GetTimeFormat , así no me vale.

Comment: En programación nada _tiene que ser con_ X o Y. Si estás haciendo un ejercicio para la escuela, está bien, pero tu pregunta debiera indicar este tipo de restricciones. Mi respuesta es válida para la pregunta original.

Comment: Es verdad ha sido error mío no indicar que tiene que ser con la función: **GetTimeFormat** , es que no se muy bien que hay que pasarle y puede ser por eso que me de error.

Comment: @jachguate :o has cambiado mi vida, no conocía `put_time`.

Comment: @DanielRuiz si necesitas usar `GetTimeFormat` la etiqueta C++11 no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la librería time.h:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char fecha[25];//ctime devuelve 26 caracteres pero tambien se podría usar un puntero de char
    time_t current_time;
    current_time=time(NULL);
    ctime(&current_time);
    strcpy(fecha, ctime(&current_time));
    printf("%s", fecha);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es que así no me vale, porque tengo que utilizar las funciones: **getLocalTime** y **getTimeFormat**. Con la función **getLocalTime** ya lo he conseguido, pero con **getTimeFormat** me falla y da error.